# Javascript output to a new tab

Tags: javascript

I need to output all these divs to a new tab. But when I click a link, only the Row 3 is outputed. What is wrong?

```
<a onclick="func()" href="javascript:void(0);">click to open all "foo" divs in a new tab</a>

<div class="foo">Row 1</div>
<div class="foo">Row 2</div>
<div class="foo">Row 3</div>

<script>
function func() {
    var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
        for (i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
                htmlContent = foo[i].innerHTML;
        }
        window.open().document.write(htmlContent);
}
</script>
```

Comment: you are replacing ` htmlContent ` with each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't declare variable 'htmlContent' with var keyword Before assigning a value to it. Check this code:-

```
  <script>
      function func() {
      var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
      var htmlContent = '';
          for (i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
                  htmlContent += foo[i].innerHTML;
          }
          window.open().document.write(htmlContent);
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

With every i increment you overwrite the html Content. change

```
htmlContent = foo[i].innerHTML;
```

with

```
htmlContent += foo[i].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm a total newbie in js. May be it's right answer, but after that change, the code shown in my post doesn't work at all.